# How do I stay on the same line?

Tags: python, newline

thanks a lot for looking at this simple problem!

Here is the problem: How do I make python stay on the same line instead of moving to a new line in this example code? Yes, it is very simple programming...I'm still learning.

enter code here

```
end1 = "C"
end2 = "h"
end3 = "e"
end4 = "e"
end5 = "s"
end6 = "e"
end7 = "B"
end8 = "u"
end9 = "r"
end10 = "g"
end11 = "e"
end12 = "r"

print( end1 + end2 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6, end =" ")
print( end7 + end8 + end9 + end10 + end11 + end12)
print("It's fleece is white., (end =" "))
print("You bet this is still on the same line!")
```

This first end="" works perfectly to say on output Cheese Burger but the next print doesn't work at all. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: You are missing a `"` and you should remove the extra `()`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out after debugging it. Special thanks to Stephen for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

im not completely sure what your trying to do but this may work

```
end1 = "C"
end2 = "h"
end3 = "e"
end4 = "e"
end5 = "s"
end6 = "e"
end7 = "B"
end8 = "u"
end9 = "r"
end10 = "g"
end11 = "e"
end12 = "r"
burger = end1 + end2 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6 + end7 + end8 + end9 + end10 + end11 + end12
print(burger)
```